# A community-specific close reason for unfocused language design questions

Tags: discussion, on-topic, close-reasons, vote-to-close

[We currently do not have any community-specific close reasons.](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/347) Broadly speaking, I don’t think this is necessarily a problem—community-specific close reasons should be created intentionally and thoughtfully to address a specific need. That said, I think we can identify one such need, namely [bringing more focus to language design questions](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/543/moving-towards-more-focused-language-design-questions).

With this in mind, I have updated our help center to note that

> - Requests for [possible language designs](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/578/are-what-are-some-possible-syntaxes-questions-on-topic) that do not provide sufficient criteria to objectively evaluate potential answers

are explicitly off-topic. Arguably, questions that are off-topic in this way could be closed using any of several existing close reasons:

- One might say they **need details or clarity** because they do not provide sufficient details about what constitutes an acceptable answer.
- One might say they **need more focus** because they should narrow their question to ask about a particular design aspect rather than some vague notion of “language design” in general.
- One might say they are **primarily opinion-based** because they do not define what constitutes a “good design”, which makes them quite subjective.

However, while I don’t think closing questions in this way would be *wrong*, I think it’s often not particularly *helpful*. For one, applying the generic close reasons in this way leaves it very ambiguous where we draw the line between an on-topic and off-topic question, which makes them difficult to apply consistently. Furthermore, from the perspective of a question asker whose question has just been closed, none of the generic close reasons provide much guidance about how they could improve their question to make it on-topic.

In my anecdotal experience thus far, these sorts of unfocused language design questions are the single most common class of good-faith questions we receive that end up closed, and they have also produced the most confusion and debate. I therefore propose that we improve this situation by creating a targeted close reason. My proposed wording is presented below; please leave an answer or comment with any tweaks or suggestions you may have.

## Proposed reason text

The [current close reason system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346638/question-close-updates) on Stack Exchange sites allows tailoring the text of each close reason based on who will see it. This section lists all the proposed variations.

### Close reason as seen by close voters

This is the wording that close voters will see in the vote-to-close menu.

> #### Lacks objective design criteria
>
> This question solicits **language designs or design tradeoffs** but does not provide sufficient criteria to objectively determine what constitutes a good answer. It should be updated to include a **specific design or implementation problem** to be solved and should provide additional context to help focus potential answers.

### General post notice

This text is shown at the top of a closed question to everyone.

> This question was **closed** because it [lacks objective design criteria](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/543). It is not currently accepting answers.

### Post-owner guidance

This text is shown under the general post notice to the author of a question.

> Answers to your question are likely to invite open-ended ideation, personal opinions, or [bikeshedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality). Please **edit** your question to include a **specific design or implementation problem** to be solved and provide additional context to help focus potential answers.

### Public guidance

This text is shown under the general post notice to everyone except the author of a question.

> Answers to this question are likely to invite open-ended ideation, personal opinions, or [bikeshedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality). If possible, consider **editing** this question to highlight a **specific design or implementation problem** to be solved and emphasize context that could help focus potential answers.

Answer (score 7):

Since this proposal seems to have been universally positively received, I’ve gone ahead and created the close reason. Use it responsibly.