# Why was my question downvoted and closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my question: [Alternative names for a value that can either be true or false?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/3638)

It got -4 and close as opinion-based. But I thought that you could ask list-style questions sometimes for brainstorming. But I did not ask which one is best, I just asked for some other options, and the existence of other options are facts not opinions so why was it closed as opinion-based?

Comment: Since you highlight the common choice of "bool" or "boolean" as something you dislike, it seems clear that the Question is opinion based.  Perhaps a broader research framing could mitigate this, making it more objective what your selection criteria are.

Answer (score 7):

For the closure, arguably it could be closed as "[lacks objective design criteria](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/587/133)" instead. This is a toss-up, but "good names" *is* seeking opinions and a classical bikeshed question, and opinion-based was fewer clicks in the moment; both are accurate. We discussed the question in chat and it was clear that there were enough votes to close, so I closed it before it got additional low-quality answers that would not fit any revised and reopened version of the question.

For the votes, I can't say *why* people downvoted it as votes are unattributed and don't have rationales attached to them. The tooltip for the downvote button says

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

so it's likely that four people thought it lacked research effort or was not useful. I can't really contest that.

However, downvotes and question closure are separated, and so in theory a question could be seen as not useful while also on-topic and answerable, or show utility and research effort while being off-topic or unanswerable. In this case, it is clearly a closeable question, but it's possible it could be edited and reopened, and then those users might change their votes, but it could also receive answers in its new, reopened form regardless.

> But I thought that you could ask list-style questions sometimes for brainstorming

I don't think this is generally true; "for brainstorming" is hardly ever going to be a workable question format under the Stack Exchange model. That is by definition just seeking unguided ideation.